# Form isSubmitted False in symfony Form with Put Method

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I use `form.factory` to create a form and twig to render the form. I have to use `PUT` method in this case. My code is:

Controller:

```
$builder = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder();
$form = $builder
    ->add('id', HiddenType::class, array('data' => $id))
    ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
        'required' => false,
        'data' => count($res['result'][0]['email']) ? $res['result'][0]['email'] : '',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control label_form_symfony'),
        'constraints' => array(
            new Email(array('message' => 'il campo Email non è valido'))
        )
    ))
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $data = $form->getData();

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // save ...
    }
}
```

Twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form,{'method':'PUT','attr':{action: path('update_xxx',{'id' : id})}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form, {'attr' : {'class' : 'label_form_symfony' } } ) }}
    <button type="submit" class="submit_form btn btn-default">Save</button>
    <div id="feedback"></div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

When I submit the form my `‌‌$request->getMethod()`is `PUT` but my `‌‌$form->isSubmitted()` is `false`.

In my HTML I have even the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

**Update**
I added 
`$builder->setMethod('PUT')` in my controller and remove `'method':'PUT'`from my twig, when I submit the form I get this error `This form should not contain extra fields.`

Answer (score 5):

The issue because of by default, `handleRequest()` method checks if form method (that has been configured for the form) is equal to request method. By default, it's `POST` for the form.

Just use `setMethod` function. `$builder->setMethod('PUT')` or you also can set it in default options in the form type class.

Comment: with  `$builder->setMethod('PUT')` I have this error `This form should not contain extra fields.`

Comment: because you forgot remove `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` -- that's an extra field.

Comment: I don't add `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` Symfony does it for me. Now I remove `'method':'PUT'`form Twig and add `$builder->setMethod('PUT')` and In my Html I have `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` because is Symfony that does it

Comment: That kind of error (this form should not contain extra fields) means that on validation you get more fields than were declared. At least  you can set `allow_extra_fields` to `true` at form options (i.e. when you create form builder)

Comment: I'd used its own Form Type (for example, `AppBundle\UpdateXXXType`) and then in controller run something like `$form = $this->createForm(UpdateXXXType::class, new UpdateXXXModel());`. In generally, you should avoid building forms inside the controllers, because if it breaks S.O.L.I.D. principles (controllers must be responsible for request and response processing only)